# Finding links matching given string in xpath/domdocument query

Tags: php, domdocument, xpath

Having issues getting links that match a given word to display using Xpath and domDocument. Everything seems to work up to where `for($i=0;$i<$documentLinks->length;$i++){` is used.

Can anyone help with where I am going wrong here?

```
$html  = '<ol>';
$html .= '  <li id="stuff-123"> some copy here </li>';
$html .= '  <li id="stuff-456"> some copy here <a href="http://domain.com">domain</a> </li>';
$html .= '  <li id="stuff-789"> some copy here </li>';
$html .= '</ol>';


    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
    $result = $xpath->query('//ol/li[starts-with(@id, "stuff")]');
    foreach($result as $e){
        $documentLinks = $e->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        for($i=0;$i<$documentLinks->length;$i++){
            $documentLink = $documentLinks->item($i);
            if(preg_match("/domain/i", $documentLink->getAttribute("href"))){
              echo $documentLink->getAttribute("href") . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't `$documentLinks` an string according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line: `$documentLinks = $e->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;`

should probably be: `$documentLinks = $e->getElementsByTagName('a');`

---

```
$e->getElementsByTagName('a')
```

returns all children of $e whose tag is `<a ...>` which means that

```
$e->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
```

is returning the first link under $e

and `$documentLinks = $e->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;`
is returning the text of that first link.

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the href attribute directly via XPath

```
//ol/li[starts-with(@id, "stuff")]/a[contains(@href, "domain")]/@href
```

and then just do

```
foreach($result as $href){
    echo $href->nodeValue;
}
```

Note that `contains` function is case-sensitive though.