# Find and append hrefs of a certain class

Tags: php, xpath, append, href

I've been searching for a solution to this but haven't found quite the right thing yet.

The situation is this:
I need to find all links on a page with a given class (say `class="tracker"`) and then append query string values on the end, so when a user loads a page, those certain links are updated with some dynamic information.

I know how this can be done with **Javascript**, but I'd really like to adapt it to run server side instead. I'm quite new to **PHP**, but from the looks of it, **XPath** might be what I'm looking for but I haven't found a suitable example to get started with. Is there anything like `GetElementByClass`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Shadowise

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding links matching given string in xpath/domdocument query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251282/finding-links-matching-given-string-in-xpath-domdocument-query)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute for an a element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace values in a URI query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777481/replace-values-in-a-uri-query-string)

Comment: the three above should contain all the information you need to solve this

Comment: @Gordon You are *still* the dupe finding king, and of course, after I have answered :P. Throwing my vote in too.

Comment: @Gordan Thanks, I will check these out!

Comment: @Gordon: From the XPath point of view this is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304791/php-simple-xpath-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything like `GetElementByClass`?

Here is an implementation I whipped up...

```
function getElementsByClassName(DOMDocument $domNode, $className) {
    $elements = $domNode->getElementsByTagName('*');
    $matches = array();
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        if ( ! $element->hasAttribute('class')) {
            continue;
        }
        $classes = preg_split('/\s+/', $element->getAttribute('class'));
        if ( ! in_array($className, $classes)) {
            continue;
        }
        $matches[] = $element;
    }
    return $matches;
}
```

This version doesn't rely on the helper function above.

```
$str = '<body>
    <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="http://example.com" class="tracker">a</a>
        <a href="http://example.com?hello" class="tracker">a</a>
    <a href="">a</a>
</body>
    ';

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($str);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($anchors as $anchor) {

    if ( ! $anchor->hasAttribute('class')) {
        continue;
    }

    $classes = preg_split('/\s+/', $anchor->getAttribute('class'));

    if ( ! in_array('tracker', $classes)) {
        continue;
    }

    $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');

    $url = parse_url($href);

    $attach = 'stackoverflow=true';

    if (isset($url['query'])) {
        $href .= '&' . $attach;
    } else {
        $href .= '?' . $attach;
    }

    $anchor->setAttribute('href', $href);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

#### Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
    <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="http://example.com?stackoverflow=true" class="tracker">a</a>
        <a href="http://example.com?hello&amp;stackoverflow=true" class="tracker">a</a>
    <a href="">a</a>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good place to get started.

To start, can I change `$dom->loadHTML($str);` to `$dom->loadHTML($html);` to parse the whole page rather than loading a string?

Comment: I think I gather how your code works, but how would I modify the `$dom->loadHTML($str)` to parse the current page for links, then edit those links in place. I need to run the script on existing pages, so passing in strings isn't really viable.

Comment: @Shadowise You'd need to use this to *preprocess* your pages. It would be much easier if you were using views on your page; you could run them through this function before outputting them.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to find all links on a page
>   with a given class (say
>   `class="tracker"`)
>   [...]
>   I'm quite new to **PHP**, but from the
>   looks of it, **XPath** might be what I'm
>   looking for but I haven't found a
>   suitable example to get started with.
>   Is there anything like
>   `GetElementByClass`?

This XPath 1.0 expression:

```
//a[contains(
       concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),
       ' tracker '
    )
]
```

Comment: BTW, would that work if it were the first or last class (considering there would not be a space either side in that example)?

Comment: @alex: Yes. That's why the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter, using xpath:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <a href="somlink" class="tracker foo">label</a>
    <a href="somlink" class="foo">label</a>
    <a href="somlink">label</a>
    <a href="somlink" class="atrackerb">label</a>
    <a href="somlink">label</a>
    <a href="somlink" class="tracker">label</a>
    <a href="somlink" class="tracker">label</a>
</root>');

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//a[contains(@class, "tracker")]') as $node) {
    if (preg_match('/\btracker\b/', $node->getAttribute('class'))) {
        $node->setAttribute(
            'href',
            $node->getAttribute('href') . '#some_extra'
        );
    }

}

header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset"UTF-8"');
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Comment: @Yoshi That appears to match elements such as `<a href="" class="atrackera"></a>`. That is why I went with splitting them :)

Comment: @Yoshi Not really matching the class then, is it? :P

Comment: @alex true, but this could also be done in the foreach loop ;)  (changed the example)

Comment: @Yoshi That will do the trick, however, can't you [use regular expressions in XPath selectors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xpath.html) as well?

Comment: @alex Yes, but php doesn't know the 'matches' function. In 5.3 one could use: registerPhpFunctions and then use preg_match in the query.